# How to change user account password to blank using batch file

Tags: user-accounts

I am having difficulty in changing password to blank using batch file.

I tried using the following command:
net user  ''

But, that will set the password into '' not blank.

Appreciate any help. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use two quotes: ""